# How to determine parameter ranges of MLlib algorithms?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parameters, apache-spark-mllib

I'm developing a Spark project in Scala. I want to create MLlib models like linear regression, naive bayes, gradient boosting regression etc.

Here what I want to try generating these models with different combinations by using their parameters. For example gradient boosting regression takes num_iters, maxDepth, learning_rate and maxBins as parameter. For now I specified some parameter ranges for this algorithm:

```
num_iters -> List.range(3,10)
maxDepth -> List.range(5,20)
maxBins -> List.range(25,50)
learning_rate -> List(0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1)
```

I searched lots of sources but I didn't find any solution.

What I want to know is how can I specify these parameter's ranges logically.

Comment: " I specify these parameter's ranges logically."  It's not clear what you mean by this. You can calculate (say) the gradient boosting regression multiple times, passing different parameters each time - just write some loops that go over the ranges for your parameters.  So what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I mean  is there any upper and lower bound for these parameters? For example learning rate should not be bigger than 1, or iteration rate should be at least 10 etc. I'm looking for these kind of general rules. Because I cannot iterate if range is too big, it's related to time and my machine's memory.

Comment: I don't know, but there seems to be some guidelines in the MLLib doc (e.g  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-decision-tree.html#usage-tips and https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-ensembles.html#usage-tips-1